# Normalizing graphs?

Tags: graphing-functions

I have a statistical line graph for a website which is all automated, but it does not look very nice. What can I do with the data (massage it, etc) to make it look better and easier to read? [The graph can be viewed here](http://biyg.org/graphs/). If something like normalizing would help, what in specific would I be looking to change?

I've considered smoothing out the line graph points, but I don't think that will help too much. I might have to change the data points somehow?

The goal would probably to look something like [Steam's stat graph](http://store.steampowered.com/stats/), is this possible?

Comment: Perhaps plot a moving average?

Comment: @DanielLittlewood Got a bit more info about that?

Comment: Well it appears the spikiness from your graph comes from having too few points with too much variance between them. To fix this you could, as in the Steam graph, collect an enormous amount of information. If this is unfeasible, you could try to 'dampen' the variations by taking a small average over a few points, and plotting these averages. So, you could split your data into sets of 4 and average them, then plot those averages.

Comment: You may also find [this link](http://www.climate4you.com/DataSmoothing.htm) helpful.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood Thanks, I should have lots of data (year or more). Extending the date range though isn't the simple solution though is it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just plot the data points and don't connect them-that would remove some clutter

I find the colors harsh-maybe you could play with them

Maybe use longer blocks of time (2 or 4 hours) to have fewer points